# How to sum result of query

Tags: php, mysql

I have one query where the output processing looks like this:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['earning'];
 }
```

And outputs result is like this:

```
 JOHN  200
 JOHN  350
 NEO   100
 NEO   220
```

What I want to achieve is that every name appears once, and "earning" is sum of all earnings of that name, like this:

```
 JOHN 550
 NEO  320
```

I have to mention that I *CANNOT* change the query; that is biggest problem.

Is there any hope?  Some suggestions? :)

Comment: the code you posted is not a query

Comment: @MarcioSimao The OP cannot change the query.

Comment: @Nikola K but it is result of query :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sum the values in the loop to another array and then output it.

Try:

```
$earnings = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!isset($earnings[$row['username']])) $earnings[$row['username']] = 0;
    $earnings[$row['username']] += $row['earning'];
}

foreach($earnings as $user => $earnings) {
    echo "$user  $earnings<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Isn't the default numeric value for an array element zero, so the `if` part is superfluous?

Comment: If you tried to operate on it before it was set, PHP will emit a notice about an undefined index, hence the `isset` check.

Comment: Really?  It is long enough since I last used PHP that it is perfectly possible, but it certainly was not always thus.

Comment: Yeah, it does:  `$results = array();

$results['test'] += 10;
var_dump($results['test']);
`  Output:  Notice: Undefined index: test in /test2.php on line 5
int(10)

Comment: As long as error_reporting is set to display notices and display_errors is on, this would be the result since at least PHP 4

Comment: So my recollections of PHP 3 being sloppy about it are probably accurate :D  I've tested a PHP 5.1.6 and indeed it complains.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :) yeah 3 was pretty sloppy, 4 represented a huge change (and rewrite) of the php interpreter

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$user = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $user[$row['username']]  += $row['earning'];
 }
```

to do echo :

```
foreach($user as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."=". $earnings."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Very bad method... It's better to use GROUP BY in query

Comment: @NikolaK. ... Which the OP _cannot do_.

Comment: @NikolaK.  Agreed, except that changing the query is prohibited, it seems.

Comment: See the answer from [drew010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318333/how-to-sum-result-of-query/11318408#11318408) that uses `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a quick solution to this answer you may want to simply append these results to an associated array and then simply loop over it to get the final count.

So, something like this:

```
 $names= array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $names[$row["username"]] += $row["earning"];
 }

 foreach($names as $k => $v) {
    echo $k." ".$v."\n";
 }
```

Comment: See the answer from [drew010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318333/how-to-sum-result-of-query/11318408#11318408) that uses `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just selecting the data, select the field and `SUM(otherfield)` with `otherfield` being the field with the number to be summed. Then add `GROUP BY` with the first field.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a change to the query, which the user cannot do, for all it is the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this in mysql side you don't need to calculate in php side so don't change your PHP side code jst change query like this

```
SELECT
  username,
  SUM(earning)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY (username)
```

hope its will work for you